# The target principal name is incorrect. Cannot generate SSPI context (SPN in cmd prompt showing existing)

Tags: sql, sql-server

We are getting the above error when tried to connect Sql server
The target principal name is incorrect. Cannot generate SSPI context

In SQL error log , I found 2 can't register SPN and Windows 0x2098 error

In `cmd` prompt when I checked

```
setspn -l Sql_service_account
```

It returned 2 records, 1 with FQDN and another one with 1433 port number

Please guide me how to proceed now please.

Comment: Here's the MS support doc for this type of error: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-troubleshoot-the-cannot-generate-sspi-context-error-message-03d15ff2-e062-e023-272c-d5cd413c37b3

Comment: On Cmd prompt when I tried to list SPN entries, It returned 2 SPN entries with FQDN, 1 without port 1433 and 1 with port 1433. Still sql throwing cant register SPN.

Comment: When I using Setspn -L <<Servername>> It is returning 4-5 entries, but in this output I couldnt find entry of mssqlsvc:\\<<sqlservername>>.                                                                          Can It be the cause of this issue.

Comment: Is there someone who can guide me

Comment: I already have SPN for sql service account in place and Still I am getting the error.